# Custom Analysis with data from SSAS 2012 : Directed Graph

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, d3.js, ssrs-2012, ssas-2012

Please I would like to know if it's possible to build an application web on top of SSAS 2012 to add custom graphic analysis ?

The problem is that the user want to visualize some relationship (Directed Graph) between entities and neither PowerView or Excel give the possibility to create a directed graph from contingency table.

So I thought to many ways to give them the possibility to visualize those relationships via Directed Graph

1. First create a web application on top of SSAS 2012 using ASP.NET MVC4, C#, D3.js : The application will plot Directed Graph using D3.js with the data collected from SSAS 2012 queried using C#. **I don't know if it's possible to query SSAS 2012 using C#**
2. Use SSRS 2012 and send periodically reports to users which will contains to Directed Graph created using D3.js. **I don't know if it's possible to use Javascript Library into SSRS 2012**
3. Use an .NET Reference Library which is able to create a Directed Graph from data directly into SSRS 2012
4. Create an application which will create the Directed Graph, save it as an image and automatically integrate the image lastly created into and SSRS 2012 reports.
5. Create an Excel or Power View plugin which will allow me to have this kind of graphic
   Which one is realizable ?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe export the data in a form that _Gephi_ can understand?  Saves you having to make an app.  Did it have to be HTTP-based?

Comment: Not really HTTP-based. I'm just looking for the easy way for the user to visualize their data like they want. The problem with Gephi is they are still obliged to learn it whereas they are just simple users who just for the most of them use 5% of Office Stack.